# Is it possible to use immutable class in Struts2 form?

Tags: struts2

Situation: I am currently moving from using Struts 1 to Struts 2. In Struts 1, it was necessary for form classes to follow the JavaBean specification. Since my business data objects are all immutable, this required creating a JavaBean version of many classes, and methods mapping between the two.

Does Struts2 support using immutable objects for forms?

If so, how do I configure it such that the immutable object is instantiated from its builder using the form fields?

Comment: You need to call Struts2 support and ask them do they support immutable objects for forms or not. You can configure actions, results, interceptors, etc. which of them do you want to use with the form fields and what did you try?

Comment: I don't understand the close or down vote. FWIW, I'm a committer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object being populated from the request can't be immutable, because OGNL calls setters on it–that's just how OGNL (and most ELs) work.

I figure you have two options: you could either do something with a custom parameters interceptor, or create a constructor or builder that takes a bean used for the form.

Without any real thought, I'd probably do the latter, although I might create a quick tool to generate the form classes if there are a lot of them. An interceptor would be more elegant, but it'd probably need to use reflection.

Comment: Thanks, Dave. I'll go with the builder accepting an instance of the form class, as I'm not a huge fan of reflection when it can be avoided.